# return array defined by a key/value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, sorting

How do I filter `return` results according to a key/value pair in an array.

Say I have this array :

```
 .factory('dishesFactory', function (){
var factory = {
    dishes :[
 {nameEnglish: 'TAPENADE',
  nameLocal: 'Tapenade',
  description: 'xxxxxx ',
  region: 'Provence-Alpes-Côte d\'Azur',
  regioncode: 'FR.B8',
  itemid: 'FR002',
  cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'FR',
  dishCategory: 'Entrée / Appetizers',
  country: 'France',
  type: 'top_10'},

 {nameEnglish: 'GREEK STYLE MUSHROOMS  ',
  nameLocal: 'Champignons à la grecque',
  description: 'xxxxxxx',
   region: 'All',
  regioncode: '',
  itemid: 'FR008',
  cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'FR',
  dishCategory: 'Entrée / Appetizers',
 country: 'France',
  type: ''}

  // more entries 

 ];
```

and I have the following  JavaScript which either returns the filtered-by-dishtype results to the user, OR return  the whole list. 
I want to change returning the whole list, by only a list of item that have `type: 'top_10'` value

```
.filter('selectedDishType', function() {
return function(dishes, dishTypes) {
    console.log(dishTypes);
    if (dishTypes.length > 0) {
        return dishes.filter(function(dish) {
            return dishTypes.indexOf(dish.dishCategory.toLowerCase()) != -1;
        });
    } else {

        return dishes;

    }
   };
 })
```

I have tried  to write a proper syntax amending the `return:dishes`, but ne in JS, cannot get something to work properly...
thanks for your help !

**HTML EDITED (SOLUTION)** 
for anyone coming across here, here is the solution I had found :

```
   .filter('selectedDishType', function() {
return function(dishes, dishTypes) { // returns ad hoc categories selected by user
    console.log(dishTypes);
    if (dishTypes.length > 0) {
        return dishes.filter(function(dish) {
            return dishTypes.indexOf(dish.dishCategory.toLowerCase()) != -1;
        });
    } else {

        return dishes.filter(function(dish){ // returns only "type =='top_10' to avoid long loading time
            return dish.type;
        });
      }
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use underscore and do something like that :

```
var the_top_10 = _.filter(dishes, function(dish){ return dish.type=='top_10'; });
```

And more generally, you can use underscore .where (http://underscorejs.org/#where)

"where_.where(list, properties) 
Looks through each value in the list, returning an array of all the values that contain all of the key-value pairs listed in properties.
"

Comment: thanks Iooks like logic is good, but not really sure where to embed the snippet in my function ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your filter function to

```
return dishes.filter(function(dish){
  return dish.type.toLowerCase().indexOf(dishTypes) != -1;
});
```

I think this code would work